# Pandas Datatype casting - How to trait comma and space-

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, data-conversion

I have a pandas DataFrame contains a column 'a' have as type Object
I'd like to convert 'a' to int type but one of rows contains data with comma like '23.,5'

The same problem with another column 'b' that contains 'space' and I can't use `.astype(float)`

My solution is :

```
df['a'] = df['a'].replace({',': ''}, regex=True)
df['a'] = df['a'].astype(float)
```

For b

```
df['b'] = df['b'].replace({' ': ''}, regex=True)
df['b'] = df['b'].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Is this a best solution ?

Comment: What was in `df['EXW']` and `df['b']` in the first place?

Comment: EXW = a -it's just an error-
**a** contains numbers but with some errors like `'2.,5' ,'10,.0', '12'`
**b** contains blank like `'5', ' ', '10', ' ' `

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your data.

If you have a variety of types in your `object` dtype series, you can just convert to `str`, apply your replacement logic, then use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html).

Note regex and whitespace replacement are *not* required:

```
s = pd.Series(['23.,5', 35.1, 425, '564', '34.133', '33 ', ' 22'])

s = pd.to_numeric(s.astype(str).str.replace(',', ''), errors='coerce')

print(s)

0     23.500
1     35.100
2    425.000
3    564.000
4     34.133
5     33.000
6     22.000
dtype: float64
```

The argument `errors='coerce'` ensures non-convertible values are replaced by `NaN`.

Of course, if all your values are already strings, then conversion to `str` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you for your respense.
I was wondering if there is a method that takes a serie of data and return all non numeric data. Because in my case I have a huge amount of data and it's difficult to look for these  non numeric data manualy

Comment: Yep, that's what `pd.to_numeric` does (with `errors='cerce'`, see edit).

Comment: if I have `s = pd.Series(['23.,5', 35b1, 42"5, '5#64', '34.133', '3/3 ', ' 22'])`, how can I fix all this errors using one methode ?

Comment: @zaki, You can't. You have to replace all the erroneous characters with what they are meant to be (e.g. `'.'`, `''`). With programming you generally need to specify what you want to do precisely.